i want to update to ubuntu 23.10 not 24.04
i want to upgrade to ubuntu 23.10 from my current version 22.04 but when I run the command
sudo do-release-upgrade 

it directly shows ubuntu version 24.04 not 23, I also tried to change the config of the file
and changed prompt=lts to normal
please help me regarding this

23,10 reached End of Life last month and is not supported anymore. Therefore no upgrade path exits. Either stick with 22.04 or upgrade to 24.04.

Ubuntu 23.10 is End of Life thus upgrades to it are no longer supported or possible using Ubuntu release-upgrader tools.
Refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/ and other 23.10 End of Life announcements.
The upgrade process for 22.04 to 24.04.1 will open officially after release of 24.04.1 which is later this month, this being the only supported upgrade path for 22.04 now.
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-24-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/46972
You can force upgrade now, but I suggest you read the "Upgrade blockers" section in the status page I provided first.

*this started out as comment only; but became answer due to length...    The key detail is https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release shows SUPPORTED: 0 thus upgrades to it are not possible... though this also gives you a method to force it ... but that would be unwise !!
